# i need to create a password checker

Tags: java

i need to initializa a secret password. while password not equal to secret password and attempts less than three keep asking the user for the password. If password correct print access granted if password incorrect print access denied max attempts reached.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker {
  public static void main (String [] args) {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String secretPassword = "alejandra";
    String password;
    int attempts = 3;

      System.out.println("Please enter password");
       password = in.nextLine ();


      while (!password.equals(secretPassword) && attempts<3) 
    System.out.println ("incorrect try again");
      password = in.nextLine ();
      if (password.equals (secretPassword)
       System.out.println ("access granted");
  }
}
```

Comment: I created an infinite loop. I'm a beginner. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password Checker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360580/password-checker)

Answer (score 3):

try this

- change to `do while`
- add braces
- set attempts to correct value
- add `)` to `if`
- increment `attempts` counter

  ```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  String secretPassword = "alejandra";
  String password;
  int attempts = 1;

  do {
    System.out.println("Please enter password");
     password = in.nextLine ();
     if (password.equals (secretPassword)) {
         System.out.println ("access granted");
         break;
     }
     if (attempts < 3)
         System.out.println ("incorrect try again");
     else 
         System.out.println ("failed");       
  }
  while (attempts++ < 3);
  ```

or if you want a `while` loop solution

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String secretPassword = "alejandra";
    String password;
    int attempts = 0;

    while (attempts++ < 3) {
      System.out.println("Please enter password");
       password = in.nextLine ();
       if (password.equals (secretPassword)) {
           System.out.println ("access granted");
           break;
       }
       if (attempts < 3)
           System.out.println ("incorrect try again");
       else 
           System.out.println ("failed");
    }
```

Comment: I need to use only the while loop. How can I do that?

Comment: i just saw the edit! I think my computer is running slow!

Comment: *I think my computer is running slow* - **mine too**

Comment: Oh, you have changed your name.  Anyway, if my question helped you please consider to upvote and/or accept - thanks

Comment: @PavneetSingh Thanks, but not holding my breath

Answer (score 0):

Have fun.

If you're emphasizing on counter, it would be best to use forloop instead of while loop because it will cause multiple attempt .

```
    public static void main (String [] args) {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String secretPassword = "alejandra";
    String password;
    int attempts = 3;

      System.out.println("Please enter password");
       password = in.nextLine ();


     for(int i=1;i<=attempts;i++){
    System.out.println ("Incorrect try again");
      password = in.nextLine ();
      if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(secretPassword)){
       System.out.println ("access granted");
  }
     }
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop because you're not changing the `attempts` variable.

Remove the `password` variable and prompt from outside of the while loop and change your while loop to:

```
while(attempts > 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    if(in.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals(secretPassword)) {
        System.out.println("access granted.");
        break;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again.");
        attempts -= 1;
    }
}
```